# Pork and waste?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

Is *pork and waste* an expression or an idiom? From the context where I picked it up, it seems to indicate that if something is "built with pork and waste" it means that some aspects of that built thing are badly and too expensively built. Is that correct?

Comment: BTW, an idiom is a type of expression established by long usage. *Pork* and its variations are idiomatic (see below), but "pork and waste" taken together are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pork* is an American slang term derived from the term *pork-barrel politics*. It is associated with *waste* and possibly *corruption* as well. From NOAD:

> **pork barrel**
>   *noun* informal
>   the use of government funds for projects designed to please voters or legislators and win votes: *political pork barrel for the benefit of their respective sponsors*
>   [ as modifier ] : *wasteful, pork-barrel spending*.

See the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_barrel) for more info on history, etc. Excerpt:

> The term pork barrel politics usually refers to spending that is intended to benefit constituents of a politician in return for their political support, either in the form of campaign contributions or votes.

Comment: I'm sure you're essentially correct, but *synonymous with 'waste' and possibly 'corruption'* is an odd thing to say in context. Obviously from a high enough perspective, government money lost through 'corruption' is 'waste' - but equally obviously, unless we assume *pork and waste* is stylistic tautology for emphasis, *pork* in this context really does mean 'corruption' (partly perhaps direct "lining of pockets", but probably mostly "non-optimal national economic decisions based purely on local electioneering considerations").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A fair point. Perhaps it would be more accurate to say "associated with waste and possibly corruption." I will edit to make that small change.

Comment: I'd say "associated with corruption (which could be seen as *wasting government funds*)".

Comment: Except that waste doesn't necessarily imply corruption. A defense spending bill that earmarks funds for the development of a weapons system that is arguably not needed may be wasteful, but not proof of corruption. And I say that as someone who grows increasingly cynical of all politics and especially that which involves lobbyists (pretty close to 100%, I'm sure). I prefer to lead with "waste" and soft-pedal "corruption" in this case.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that *pork* in this context **always** implies corruption. The *waste* connotation may or may not attach to *pork/corruption*. In this specific case I'd be inclined to distance it, so *pork and waste* can be read as two different (but related) "bad things", rather than just the same thing being said twice. In short, you're biasing the statement towards your own "political/sociological" leanings, contrary to the original writer's choice of phrase.

Comment: @Fumble: it looks to me as if the pot is calling the kettle black.  'Pork barrel politics' is not the same as corruption; arguably it is a politician's duty to request that the military base should be built in his constituency.  If the military put that above other considerations then there is a failure of government, but neither the general nor the politician are (on this evidence) corrupt. Certainly it accompanies corruption, as much waste, which is where we came in.

Comment: There seems to be some acceptable level for political corruption -- where people just shrug, what do you expect? -- everywhere, though what the level is varies greatly. What's considered real corruption is above that level, and _pork barrel_ works for both. _Pork-barrel_ is a very rich metaphor, with loads of _fat_ dripping off (for people to catch), lots of _rich meat_ (for those equipped to cook and eat it), and haphazard construction (how do you think they squeeze all that pork in the barrel, anyway?).

Comment: @Fumble: I understand your point. I just disagree with it.

Comment: @TimLymington: Possibly, but as per my comment to Robusto, I think you're introducing personal "political/sociological" attitudes here. IMHO the reason people use the term *pork barrel politics* is significantly affected by association with the the politician and local cronies etc. getting their *snouts in the trough*, and similar references to pigs.

Comment: @Robusto: Fair enough. We're both capable of making up our own minds on such issues, and it's no big deal if we don't actually agree. I only really stuck my oar in (a) in case you'd written something carelessly and might wish to change it, and (b) so other visitors can see there is an alternative viewpoint. Protracted nitpicking at this level doesn't do any of us (or ELU itself) much good.

Comment: Given my identity, it would be irresponsible for me not to contribute some little thing here. Obviously, I love piggies and cannot give an unbiased answer to the question. But the answer to this question concerning *pork barrel politics*  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45582/is-there-a-connection-between-pork-barrel-and-gravy-train may be helpful.

Comment: Pork barrel normally implies a local geographical connection. A contract would be given to a company in a particular area in return for cooperation of a politician from that area - so even if there isn't criminal corruption (the politician receiving money) it is buying votes and arguably political corruption.